# How To make a giveaway Command in Discord.py?

Tags: python, command, discord.py

So I tried using this code for a giveaway command, but for some reason it never shows a reaction for users to enter. I tried changing the giveaway icon, maybe rerunning the code, but no luck.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role("Admin")
async def gstart(ctx, mins: int, *, prize: str):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Giveaway!",
                          description=f"{prize}",
                          color=ctx.author.color)

    end = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=mins * 60)

    embed.add_field(name="Ends At:", value=f"{end} UTC")

    my.msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await my.msg.add_reaction("")

    await asyncio.sleep(mins)

    new_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(my_msg.id)

    users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()

    users.pop(users.index(client.user))

    winner = random.choice(users)

    await ctx.send(f"Congratulations! {winner.mention} won {prize}!")


@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def reroll(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, id_: int):
    try:
        new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(id_)
    except:
        await ctx.send(
            "The ID that was entered was incorrect, make sure you have entered the correct giveaway message ID."
        )
    users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    users.pop(users.index(client.user))

    winner = random.choice(users)

    await channel.send(
        f"Congratulations the new winner is: {winner.mention} for the giveaway rerolled!"
    )
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I would also like to know if I can use d for days h for hours etc. to set the duration of the giveaway.

Comment: Thats a separate question, but take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64545847/tempmute-command-with-converting-time-in-discord-py)

Answer (score 2):

I noticed you put "my.msg" as your variable name, the official python documentation does not allow you to make variables with a dot in the name as this is a reserved keyword. Might I suggest instead changing it to:

```
my_msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
await my_msg.add_reaction("")
```

Comment: Oh also, should I do new.message instead of new_message as well?

Comment: anything that has a "." as a variable name is invalid. Make sure your variable names conform with [python variable naming rules](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_variable_names.asp)

Comment: Ok, but also, I have mins written down, but it calculates it has seconds. I tried 5 mins but it did 5 secs.

Comment: because you havent done the conversion yet, a variable name does nothing, its only a name. You have to convert seconds into minutes, just do mins multiplied 60 and pass that value into the code